# ASP.NET Core Razor pages caching not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0, .net-8.0

My response always has no cache, no store as Cache Control header. I followed the Microsoft article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-8.0

[Cache Control header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOcXg.png)

This is my `IndexModel`:

```
 [ResponseCache(VaryByHeader = "User-Agent", Duration = 30)]
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
 {
     private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

     public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
     }
     
     public void OnGet()
     {
     }
 }
```

In my `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

builder.Services.AddResponseCaching();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var emailConfig = builder.Configuration
                         .GetSection("EmailConfiguration")
                         .Get<EmailConfiguration>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton(emailConfig);

if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // builder.Services.AddWebOptimizer();

    // builder.Services.AddWebOptimizer(minifyJavaScript: false, minifyCss: false);
}

// builder.Services.AddSitemap();

builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");

builder.Services.AddWebMarkupMin(options =>
        {
            options.AllowMinificationInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
            options.AllowCompressionInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
        })
        .AddHtmlMinification(options =>
            {
                options.MinificationSettings.RemoveRedundantAttributes = true;
                options.MinificationSettings.RemoveHttpProtocolFromAttributes = true;
                options.MinificationSettings.RemoveHttpsProtocolFromAttributes = true;
            })
        .AddHttpCompression();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseWebMarkupMin();

//app.UseWebOptimizer();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/404");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseResponseCaching();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
        new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };
    context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] =
        new string[] { "Accept-Encoding" };

    await next();
});
```

I have been stuck on this for the past 2 days. What am I missing?

Comment: The issue is in the client.  The request was sent from client to server and server responded with a 200 OK and the data in the body of the response is GZIP.  GZIP is compression so you need to uncompress.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: Thank you. Are you saying that since it is Gzip I cannot have Cache Control? meaning I can either have one of it?

Comment: You are getting a good response.  The data is compressed.  You can have GZIP with Cache.  Cache just means the data is kept in memory.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-8.0